# How to trigger an event when a QListWidget has contents added or removed

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5, qlistwidget

When adding elements to a QListWidget I want to enable or disable an action depending if there are elements in the QListWidget. Is there something list `listWidget.itemChanged.connect(self.checkListLength)` except for change in number of elements in the QlistWidget I could use? Normally after Each change to the Widget I would just do the check but many different sources will be changing it and it would make more sense to just listen for the change.

I've tried every connect I could find to see if it would return the desired result and it doesn't seem to.

Here is an example that compiles but doesn't enable the action `Rename Selection`. We're importing filenames into the QListWidget. In this example we could just enable it after using the open folder but for my code it won't be that easy.

```py
import sys
from os import listdir
from os.path import isfile, join
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (
    QMainWindow, QAction, QHBoxLayout, QWidget, QListWidget, 
    QListWidgetItem, QAbstractItemView, QApplication, QDialog, qApp, QToolBar, QFileDialog
)
from PyQt5.QtGui import QIcon
from PyQt5 import QtCore

class MainGui(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.mainWidget = QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.mainWidget)
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):  
        #TopIcon
        self.exitAct = QAction(QIcon('img/x-square.svg'), 'Exit', self)
        self.exitAct.setShortcut('Ctrl+Q')
        self.exitAct.triggered.connect(qApp.quit)

        #Import Folder
        self.importAct = QAction(QIcon('img/folder.svg'), 'Open Folder', self)
        self.importAct.setShortcut('Ctrl+N')
        self.importAct.triggered.connect(self.getFolder)

        #Rename Button
        self.renameAct = QAction(QIcon('img/edit.svg'), 'Rename Selection', self)
        self.renameAct.setShortcut('Ctrl+R')
        self.renameAct.setEnabled(False)

        self.toolbar = QToolBar('ToolBar')
        self.addToolBar(QtCore.Qt.LeftToolBarArea, self.toolbar)
        self.toolbar.addAction(self.exitAct)
        self.toolbar.addSeparator()
        self.toolbar.addAction(self.importAct)
        self.toolbar.addAction(self.renameAct)
        self.hbox = QHBoxLayout()
        self.listWidget = QListWidget()
        self.listWidget.setSelectionMode(QAbstractItemView.ExtendedSelection)
        self.listWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 10, 211, 291))
        self.hbox.addWidget(self.listWidget)
        self.mainWidget.setLayout(self.hbox)
        self.show()

    def getFolder(self):
        self.ImportFolder = QFileDialog.getExistingDirectory(None, "Select Directory") 
        self.getFilesInDir(self.ImportFolder)

    def getFilesInDir(self, mypath):
        f = []
        files = [f for f in listdir(mypath) if isfile(join(mypath, f))]
        if files:
            self.listWidget.addItems(files)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    gui = MainGui()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to know if an item was added or removed to the QListWidget, you must do it through the internal model that has the `rowsInserted` and `rowsRemoved` signals, respectively.

```
import sys
from os import listdir
from os.path import isfile, join
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class MainGui(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.mainWidget = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.mainWidget)
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        # TopIcon
        self.exitAct = QtWidgets.QAction(
            QtGui.QIcon("img/x-square.svg"), "Exit", self
        )
        self.exitAct.setShortcut("Ctrl+Q")
        self.exitAct.triggered.connect(QtWidgets.qApp.quit)

        # Import Folder
        self.importAct = QtWidgets.QAction(
            QtGui.QIcon("img/folder.svg"), "Open Folder", self
        )
        self.importAct.setShortcut("Ctrl+N")
        self.importAct.triggered.connect(self.getFolder)

        # Rename Button
        self.renameAct = QtWidgets.QAction(
            QtGui.QIcon("img/edit.svg"), "Rename Selection", self
        )
        self.renameAct.setShortcut("Ctrl+R")
        self.renameAct.setEnabled(False)

        self.toolbar = QtWidgets.QToolBar("ToolBar")
        self.addToolBar(QtCore.Qt.LeftToolBarArea, self.toolbar)
        self.toolbar.addAction(self.exitAct)
        self.toolbar.addSeparator()
        self.toolbar.addAction(self.importAct)
        self.toolbar.addAction(self.renameAct)
        hbox = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(self.mainWidget)
        self.listWidget = QtWidgets.QListWidget()
        self.listWidget.setSelectionMode(
            QtWidgets.QAbstractItemView.ExtendedSelection
        )
        self.listWidget.model().rowsInserted.connect(self.on_rowsInserted)
        self.listWidget.model().rowsRemoved.connect(self.on_rowsRemoved)
        hbox.addWidget(self.listWidget)
        self.show()

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot(QtCore.QModelIndex, int, int)
    def on_rowsInserted(self, parent, first, last):
        print("Insert:", parent, first, last)

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot(QtCore.QModelIndex, int, int)
    def on_rowsRemoved(self, parent, first, last):
        print("Remove:", parent, first, last)

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def getFolder(self):
        importFolder = QtWidgets.QFileDialog.getExistingDirectory(
            None, "Select Directory"
        )
        self.getFilesInDir(importFolder)

    def getFilesInDir(self, mypath):
        files = [f for f in listdir(mypath) if isfile(join(mypath, f))]
        if files:
            self.listWidget.addItems(files)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    gui = MainGui()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm sorry for answering my own question, but I figured it out and didn't want to leave anyone hanging.

You need to reference the QListWidget's model in order to do this:

```py
self.lwModel = self.listWidget.model()
self.lwModel.rowsInserted.connect(self.checkListLength) #Any time an element is added run function
self.lwModel.rowsRemoved.connect(self.checkListLength) #Any time an element is removed run function
```

I hope that helps anyone with the same issue.

Comment: Really helped me with my project! For some reason whenever I tried to scroll to the bottom of the list widget each time I inserted something, it wouldn't work. Using this method worked like a charm though! Kudos!